# is there a faster way to check the user's state in firebase like onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, next.js

I have currently working on a next.js project using react, redux and firebase.
When user enters a page that need authorization I use the following code to redirect them if they are not authenticated.

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

import { firebase } from '../../firebase';
import * as routes from '../../constants/routes';

const withAuthorization = (needsAuthorization) => (Component) => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        if (!authUser && needsAuthorization) {
          Router.push(routes.SIGN_IN)
        }
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component { ...this.props } />
      );
    }
  }

  return WithAuthorization;
}

export default withAuthorization;
```

I am using the following [repo](https://github.com/taming-the-state-in-react/nextjs-redux-firebase-authentication) as my base project. The problem is the app seems to work fine but when I try to navigate to a page that requires authentication when I am not authenticated. I am not redirected immediately rather it shows the page first then redirects. Since the HOC uses

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged()
```

which is asynchronous. Is there a faster way of checking  if the user is logged in.

I have so far considered the

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

but my internal state depends on the update of the onAuthStateChanged function when the user logs out in another page.

Answer (score 0):

Using a listener to `onAuthStateChanged` is usually the correct way to restore authentication state upon a full page transition. Since there is a reload happening at such a transition, there is a chance that the authentication state has changed. Using an `onAuthStateChanged` listener ensures that Firebase calls your code after it has validated the authentication state of the user. Since this may require a call to the server, this can indeed takes some time, so you'll want to show a "loading..." animation.

If the state transition doesn't require a reload, like when you're just rendering a new route in the same page, then you can be reasonably certain that the authentication state doesn't change on the transition. In that case you could pass the current user from the previous component into the new one. Tyler has a good article on this: [Pass props to a component rendered by React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/).

In the latter case `firebase.auth().currentUser` should also retain its state, and you can use it safely. You'd then still use an `onAuthStateChanged` to detect changes in authentication state after the new route has loaded.